# How to pass a variable in match function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Firstly this may sound like a duplicate question but I was unable to resolve my problem using the previous asked questions:
This is my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>

    function test() {
      var totalids='XYZ@@';
      var variable_name=document.getElementById('p1').value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''); 
      var result = totalids.match(/variable_name/i);
      if (result){
        alert('Matched');
      } else {
        alert("Not Matched");
      }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="click on me" onclick="test()">
     <input type="text" value="xyz" id="p1">
 </body>
 </html>
```

This program is not matching my String.I want to match my string using case-insensitive match.I know the problem lies in this line:

```
 var result = totalids.match(/variable_name/i);
```

I am unable to pass variable in match function.I can do this;

```
 var re = new RegExp(str1, "g");
```

But I don't know how to do cases-insensitive search using above line.

Comment: You can use: `var re = new RegExp(variable_name, "gi");` to make it case insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how:

```
var re = new RegExp(str1, "gi");
```

Comment: Should i delete my question then Now i think this is a very dumb question.

Comment: I don't think it is! But it's your call. In the process of learning we all make such mistakes, and it's alright. It's part of learning ... and now you may never forget.

Comment: OK i won't may be it will help others

Comment: If it's not a duplicate, it should definitely stick around. This is a common problem and the answer will help a lot of people down the road.